# Непонятная ошибка: request for member 'length' in 'email', which is of non-class type 'int*'

Tags: c++

Вот мой код:

```
std::string resolve_email(int *email){

    char* c = new char[email.length() + 1];//error: request for member 'length' in 'email', which is of non-class type 'int*'

    for(int i = 0; i < email.length(); i++){
        c[i] = email[i];//error: request for member 'length' in 'email', which is of non-class type 'int*'
    }
    return std::string(c);
}
```

Я получаю при компиляции ошибки (добавил в код как комментарий).
Что здесь не так?

Comment: Wrong language. English is working language at stackoverflow.com, but you are at ru.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: я понял это, спасибо

Comment: Судя по коду, вы хотите получить копию `email` в типе `std::string`. Откуда у вас аргумент `email` в виде массива целых чисел?

Answer (score 1):

С какого языка перебрались на C++?

Указатель ничего не знает о том, на сколько элементов он указывает, так что длину массива надо передавать вместе с указателем.

Но что вы, собственно, хотите сделать? Мне вообще непонятна цель ваших телодвижений: создать массив `char`, обрубить `int` до `char` и запихать это зачем-то в строку, еще и вызвав утечку памяти.

Изложите свою цель, потому что можно только догадываться, что вы хотите... И делаете это ужасно неверно.

Comment: я на c++ уже долго не писал(больше года. в основном python и JS).

Comment: как сделать, чтобы массив символов принял размер массива int

Comment: Используйте не массив, а `vector`, или передавайте в функцию второй параметр - длину массива. Но вы вообще явно делаете что-то не то! Давайте не спрашивать, какой рукой держать микроскоп для забивания гвоздей - расскажите о самих гвоздях, чтоб подобрать, чем их забивать.